# How to press "ALT+F4" using AutoIt

Tags: autoit, notepad, alt-key

I am new in AutoIt. I have run the notepad by using the following code in AutoIt:

```
Run("notepad.exe")
```

Now I want to quit the application by using "ALT+F4". How to press "ALT+F4" with AutoIt tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to check out the documentation for AutoIt - which is pretty good.

The one you're looking for is: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm

Keep in mind that you want to make sure that the window is active or that you're targeting the window.

With that, I recommend using this : https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm

> ControlSend() works in a similar way to Send() but it can send key
>   strokes directly to a window/control, rather than just to the active
>   window.

Comment: I would like to add that this link has a list of all keys you can send, which will help put together the required combination: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm

Comment: Thanks McAdam331 for providing the good link.

Answer (score 3):

The following code for pressing "ALT+F4" should work in AutoIt:

```
Send("{ALT down}{F4 down}{F4 up}{ALT up}")
```

OR,

```
Send("!{F4}")
```

OR,

```
Send("!{F4}", 0)
```